# How to upgrade bootstrap in a .net core 2 web site

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, bower, asp.net-core-2.0, nuget-package

I´m pretty sure this is very easy but I couldn´t figure out how to upgrade bootstrap from 3.3.7 to 4.1.1.

What i did was changing this in the _layout page, according to the version

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
```

What else is needed.

I also saw in Nuget package manager, but I think that will require more changes, and I don´t know how to do it, keeping control on the versions and the project itself.

**UPDATE**

I found a bower.json file in wwwroot/lib/bootstrap folder, and I modified it everuwhere 3.3.7 and replace it with 4.1.1, however there is a commit number I don´t know what it is.

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "description": "The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "js",
    "less",
    "mobile-first",
    "responsive",
    "front-end",
    "framework",
    "web"
  ],
  "homepage": "http://getbootstrap.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "moduleType": "globals",
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "/.*",
    "_config.yml",
    "CNAME",
    "composer.json",
    "CONTRIBUTING.md",
    "docs",
    "js/tests",
    "test-infra"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3"
  },
  "version": "4.4.1",
  "_release": "4.4.1",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "v4.1.1",
    "commit": "0b9c4a4007c44201dce9a6cc1a38407005c26c86"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git",
  "_target": "v4.1.1",
  "_originalSource": "bootstrap",
  "_direct": true
}
```

this is not working. The layout reference to bootstrap cdn is still pointing to 3.3.7 and the bootstrap files in lib folder were not updated when I save the bower file.

Comment: You go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution. There are 4 tabs: Browse, Installed, Updates and Consolidate. If you are lucky enough, Updates will have a number beside it. Just update from there. For `Version(s)` at the right, just select both 'Project' and <Your project name>

Comment: Hum.. 1) I don't specify the bootstrap version in _layout page. Yes I have only `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`. 2) I use bower.json to specify the version.

Comment: They did change something in the latest VS2017. so now they don´t use bower, which was pretty easy, but now they offer better control for what you wnat to use and how on development and release. I´m gonna check what you siad. My solution does not have bower file

Comment: I was wrong. I found a bower.json file in the wwwroot/lib/nootstrap folder in the solution explorer. But I couldn´t figure out how to change it. I change all 3.3.7 version to 4.1.1, but there is a commit nmber I don´t know if it is correct or not. gonna update the question

Comment: Let's get this straight. In the project root folder, there is a bower.json file you used to specify the version of bootstrap. Once you save, the bootstrap with version you are looking for will be loaded into ~/wwwroot/lib. In the ~/wwwroot/lib/boostrap, yes there is also a bower.json, but leave that file. Don't modify it. At this point of time, the best thing for you is to remove ~/wwwoort/lib/boostrap. Create a bower.json at project root. Enter as what is in my answer for bower.json and save. That will bring bootstrap again.

Comment: I agree with removing it first and the reload it. I was checking also that bower is losing support and now they recommend NPM. is that true, as this is going to be a long time project I would like to have all the information before proceeding.

Comment: Bower is under maintenance. Even at bower page, it says to use either `Yarn` or `Webpack`. Read https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/ to find out more. By the way, you really have to look into your project. As my original answer indicates, your project looks straight. If in doubt, recreate another project but choose dot net core. Then copy files of your own logic over.

Comment: gnna try that to. yesterday I could remove most of the jquery nd bootstrp bower references and install them from NPM. it seems to be working quite good, fortunately my project is only three views, because almost everything has to be rewritten.

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio 2017 15.7 you can use the not yet released [LibMan](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/wiki) (Library Manager) to get the latest Bootstrap library.

1. Open your web project
2. Go to Tools -> Nuget Package Manager->Nuget Package Manager Console
3. Type

   ```
   PM>Install-Package Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build -Version 1.0.113
   ```
4. Once Library Manager is installed, create a libman.json on the root of your solution
5. Format your libman.json as below

   ```
   {
     "version": "1.0",
     "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
     "defaultDestination": "wwwroot/lib",
     "libraries": [
       {
         "library": "jquery@3.0.0",
         "files": [
           "core.js",
           "jquery.js",
           "jquery.min.js",
           "jquery.min.map",
           "jquery.slim.js",
           "jquery.slim.min.js",
           "jquery.slim.min.map" 
         ],
         "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery"
       },
       {
         "library": "twitter-bootstrap@4.1.3",
         "files": [
           "css/bootstrap-grid.css",
           "css/bootstrap-grid.css.map",
           "css/bootstrap-grid.min.css",
           "css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.map",
           "css/bootstrap-reboot.css",
           "css/bootstrap-reboot.css.map",
           "css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css",
           "css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map",
           "css/bootstrap.css",
           "css/bootstrap.css.map",
           "css/bootstrap.min.css",
           "css/bootstrap.min.css.map",
           "js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
           "js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map",
           "js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
           "js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map",
           "js/bootstrap.js",
           "js/bootstrap.js.map",
           "js/bootstrap.min.js",
           "js/bootstrap.min.js.map" 
         ],
         "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Then rebuild your solution. voila!

Comment: Thanks for the example! I kept looking for "bootstrap" and only finding addons.

Comment: Note that since this question was answered LibMan has been release and is now part of Visual Studio. You don't have to install nuget package anymore, it is part of the "web developement tools".

Answer (score 3):

While I was tackling this issue I came across this post.  I figured I would chime in, in-case some were looking for a decent solution.

The template itself features a 'one-time' inclusion of bootstrap 3.3.7. Unfortunately, while the direction the ASP.NET Core team is in flux, some of the front end features are certainly lacking.

> Bower is now depricated https://bower.io/blog/

Some have migrated to Grunt or Gulp or Yarn + Webpack. Also at some point ASP.NET Core included a `gulpfile` in the project template, but it never made it past RC into the stable version. Setting up your project to use any of the platforms for this is an undertaking and some, like myself are just looking for a band-aid instead of having to learn new platforms, or lean heavily on Node.js (NPM)

So, below is how I tackled this:

1. Install NPM
2. Create an empty project `npm init`
3. Install dependencies

   - `npm install bootstrap`
   - `npm install font-awesome` *note1
   - `npm install jquery`
   - `npm install popper.js`
4. Copy the folders from /node_modules/ to /wwwroot/lib/ *note2
5. Change replace the css links and script tags in your your `_Layout.cs` with the below code.

> Note 1: Bootstrap 3.3.7 had glyphicons, if you want icons in your web project, I (and Bootstrap) recommends Font-Awesome. Font-Awesome at the time of writing is 5.1.0. I chose not to use the new version. If you want the latest version, you'll need to use `npm install font-awesome-free`
>
> Note 2: You do NOT need all these files, but for brevity sake I didn't list the minimum required files. For the most part you only need what is in the `<dependency>\dist\` folder.

---

## _Layout.cshtml

***In the `<head>` tag***

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only"
          asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
```

***Before the `</body>` tag***

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
@* Get your own CDN link from 
   https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/
*@
    <script src="SEE ABOVE NOTE"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.Popper" 
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to use NuGet. Instead you should use bower.json. Also your _layout may not be correct.

For me, I specify the version information in bower.json. Here is what I have:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "jquery": "~3.3.1",
    "jquery-validation": "~1.17.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "~3.2.9",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "font-awesome": "~5.0.10",
    "bootswatch": "~3.3.7"
  }
}
```

For you, you can specify the bootstrap version to be 4.1.1. Once save, the appropriate bootstrap will be downloaded automatically.

In my _layout page, I have only the following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Travel Agency - @ViewBag.Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootswatch/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
```

Hope this helps.